# How to do this search in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My task is to create a statement to answer this:

**List each author (by lastname and firstname) and the number of books that the author has written.**

The database has three tables that will be used

book table with isbn (primary), title, type, pub_id, price, advance, ytd_sales, pub_date

bookauthor table(which is in between book and author) with, author_id(primary), isbn, author_order, royaltyshare

author table with, author_id(primary), ssn, lastname, firstname, phone, address, city, state, zip

```
select author.lastname, author.firstname, bookauthor.count(author_id)
from author a
join bookauthor ba on ba.author_id = a.author_id
group by lastname
```

That is what I got but it isn't working and for whatever reason, I am having a hard time understanding these type of SQL statements with join and in and those types of statements. If anyone could help explain the process more, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Just because two authors have the same name, it doesn't mean that they are the same person. That's why you have an author_id!

Comment: @Strawberry good point. I've updated my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues. From the start of the query:

1. When you define a table alias (`a` is the alias for `author`) you **must** use that alias everywhere you specifically refer to the `author` table, so in your `SELECT` you should say `SELECT a.lastname, a.firstname`;
2. When you want to `COUNT` something, the table name goes inside the `COUNT`, and again you must use the table alias you defined: `COUNT(ba.author_id)`
3. You could use a column alias for your count to make it easier to refer to e.g. `COUNT(ba.author_id) AS num_books`
4. You should use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you can list authors that have written no books (if there are any)
5. To be strictly compliant, you should `GROUP BY` all non-aggregated columns, so this needs to be `GROUP BY a.lastname, a.firstname`.
6. As was pointed out by @Strawberry, you should really group by `author_id`, since it is possible two authors have the same name. Since `author_id` is a primary key, in MySQL it is OK to only group by that field, however SQL server requires that you still group by `lastname` and `firstname` as well.

In total, your query should be:

```
SELECT a.lastname, a.firstname, COUNT(ba.author_id) AS num_books
FROM author a
LEFT JOIN bookauthor ba ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY a.author_id, a.lastname, a.firstname
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you alias a table, you need to use the alias when you later refer to that table:

```
select 
    a.lastname, 
    a.firstname, 
    TotalBooksForAuthor = count(a.author_id)
from 
    author a
    join bookauthor ba on ba.author_id = a.author_id
group by
    a.author_id,
    a.lastname,
    a.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `firstname` in `group by`. Also the way you have used `count` is not right. Try the following.

```
select 
    lastname, 
    firstname, 
    count(author_id) as total_books
from author a
join bookauthor ba 
on ba.author_id = a.author_id
group by 
    lastname,
    firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include all the columns in select in your `group by` and secondly once you have aliased a table then use that aliased name everywhere:

```
select  a.firstname, a.lastname, count(ba.author_id)
from author a
join bookauthor ba on ba.author_id = a.author_id
group by a.firstname, a.lastname
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this SQL syntax:

```
SELECT a.lastname + ', '+ a.firstname, COUNT(b.author_id)
FROM author AS a
LEFT JOIN bookauthor AS b ON a.author_id = b.author_id
GROUP BY a.lastname, a.firstname
```